# D3js "bars.enter().attr" is not a function

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I've brought some of my code to match D3 standards. But now I'm having issues with my update function working. I'm trying to follow the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

When I run the function, I get an error in the console: `"TypeError: gbars.enter(...).attr is not a function"`

```
function updateBars()
{   
   xScale.domain(d3.range(dataset.length)).rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
   yScale.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return (d.local > d.global) ? d.local : d.global;})]); 


   var gbars = svg.selectAll("rect.global")
       .data(dataset);

   gbars.enter()
       .attr("x", w)
       .attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d.global); })
       .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
       .attr("height", function(d) {return yScale(d.global);});

   gbars.transition()
       .duration(500)
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i);
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.global);
       })
       .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
       .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.global);
       });

   gbars.exit()
       .transition()
       .duration(500)
       .attr("x", -xScale.rangeBand())
       .remove();
}
```

I understand, I probably have a lot of errors with the update function in general, but it's hard to troubleshoot when hung-up at the beginning.

My goal for the update will be to remove/add series from the chart. They can choose to display Global, Local, or both (default). I'd actually prefer that when they hover over the legend it shows only that series. On mouseout, it would go back to default.

[**Working Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/Hv867/7/).

Comment: I have fixed the title to match your actual error message. I found this question because I have actually encountered a situation where *enter* is not a function, not anything called after `enter()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to say what you want to do for new nodes. Yes it's almost always append but you still have to tell it:

```
   gbars.enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("class", "global")
       .attr("x", w)
```

Other than that error, your structure for general update pattern looks correct on the surface.